# Push notification in view based app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, push-notification

I created a view based app. In a view Controller class I created a tab bar Dynamically. The App is running fine, but I am having a problem with handling a push-notification. While Push-notification  sent means I received the push alert, I want to know how to show selected index 3 of my Tab bar.

in the view based application after 2 class i create this tabbar dynamically.

tabbar1 = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

```
    tab_obj1 = [[First alloc] initWithNibName:@"First" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *tabItem1 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: tab_obj1] autorelease];
    tabItem1.title=@"First";
    tabItem1.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"FirstIcon.png"];
    tab_obj2 = [[Second alloc] initWithNibName:@"Second" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *tabItem2 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: tab_obj2] autorelease];

    tabItem2.title=@"Second";
    tabItem2.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"SecondSelc.png"];

    tab_obj3 = [[Third alloc] initWithNibName:@"Third" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *tabItem3 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: tab_obj3] autorelease];

    tabItem3.title=@"Third";
    tabItem3.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"ThirdIcon.png"];
    tab_obj4 = [[Fourth alloc] initWithNibName:@"Fourth" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Could you please provide code examples/what you have tried?

Comment: I provide some code to create dynamic tabbar in the viewbased application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Developers,
 Thanks for responding me.
I will show that badge value inside the tabBar tab.
I create tabBar controls again in **didReceiveRemoteNotification** method and in non-active state app from this
 
`tabbarcontroller_obj.tabBarItem.badgeValue=@"3"`
 Like this I handle the notification badge value inside the application.

Answer (score 2):

Write your code to select tabbar index in the below method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo   {
    // Notification code here
}
```

Above Method calls everytime notification comes, so you can write your code here for the selection of tabbar index.

Comment: Notification come inside this function. from this i checked active state and inactive state from this i cont redirect specific tab.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has nothing to do with Push Notification...

To show any given tab of your TabBarController, you can do something like this:

```
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3;
```

where `tabBarController` is a pointer to your application's tab bar controller object.

There are special considerations for changing `selectedIndex` to a value that represents the More controller. Check the documentation for `UITabBarController` and the `selectedIndex` property for the details.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But this for tabbar based application.Here I am using viewbased application in that I Create Dynamically tabbar controller. so that I am facing this problem to handle.I added some code above.Please refer it and give idea please. thanks in advance.\

Comment: Oh. I see... Well, first you have add your tab bar controller's view to your main window, so it's visible at all. Then, the suggestion I made in my answer will work. Look at the template for a tab bar-based app to see how to add the tab bar controller's view to your main window.